# I am trying to upload a image from an folder into my program, I think my syntax is OK but I don't know why It doesn't work.

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

This is my load code, I can't understand were I did wrong:

```
case WM_CREATE: 
        hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(0, TEXT("D:/ECG/Games/n.bmp"), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
        GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm); 
        //imgRgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight);
        SetTimer(hWnd, TIMER_1, 30, NULL);
        break;
```

Comment: You don't know why it doesn't work because you omitted all required error handling and reporting.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
    hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(0, TEXT("D:\ECG\Games\n.bmp"), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
```

`\` instead of `/`